# Create 2nd tables and add data

Tags: php, mysql

I have this task from school, and I am confuse and lost on how I got to do this.
So basically I have to create 2 tables to the database but I have to created from php.

I have created the first table, but not the second one for some reason.
And then, I have to populate first and second tables with 10 and 20 sample records respectively, populate, does it mean like adding more fake users? if so is it like the code shown below?

*I got error on the populating second part as well

Thank you so much for the help.

```
<?php
        $host = "host";
        $user = "me";
        $pswd = "password";
        $dbnm = "db";

        $conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pswd, $dbnm);
        if (!$conn)
            die ("<p>Couldn't connect to the server!<p>");

        $selectData = @mysqli_select_db ($conn, $dbnm);
        if(!$selectData)
        {
            die ("<p>Database Not Selected</p>");
        }

        //1st table
            $sql =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `friends`  
          (  
          `friend_id` INT NOT NULL auto_increment,   
          `friend_email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
          `password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
          `profile_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
          `date_started` DATE NOT NULL,  
          `num_of_friends` INT unsigned,  
          PRIMARY KEY (`friend_id`)  
          )";

        //2nd table
          $sqlMyfriends = "CREATE TABLE `myfriends`
          (  
          `friend_id1` INT NOT NULL,   
          `friend_id2` INT NOT NULL,
          )";


        $query_result1 = @mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $query_result2 = @mysqli_query($conn, $sqlMyfriends);

        //populating 1st table
        $sqlSt3="INSERT INTO friends (friend_id, friend_email, password, profile_name, date_started, num_of_friends) 
                VALUES('NULL','email@email.com','123','abc','2012-10-25', 5)";
        $queryResult3 = @mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sqlSt3)


        //populating 2nd table
        $sqlSt13="INSERT INTO myfriends VALUES(1,2)";
        $queryResult13=@mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sqlSt13);


        mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors? Don't do that. How will you know what's going wrong?

Comment: Trailing comma after the `friend_id2` declaration.  Remove the `@` and always check the result with `if(!$query_result2){ echo mysql_error(); }`

Comment: Thx Michael, btw Waleed, what do you mean by suppressing errors?

Comment: When you prepend `@` to any php expression, it will ignore any error messages - [php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The others have addressed one of your issues, so this is in relation to not being able to add values to your tables (populate). Your connection link is `$conn` -

```
$conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pswd, $dbnm);
ie.
   $query_result1 = @mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

but when you are adding your values to the tables, you changed your connection link to `$dbConnect`

```
...
$queryResult3 = @mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sqlSt3)
...
$queryResult13=@mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sqlSt13);
```

---

To insert multiple values into your table you could add a comma and additional parentheses `,()` -

```
    //populating 2nd table
    $sqlSt13="INSERT INTO myfriends VALUES(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)";
    $queryResult13=@mysqli_query($conn,$sqlSt13);
```

Or you could use `mysqli_multi_query`, and list each one-

```
    //populating 2nd table
    $sqlSt13  ="INSERT INTO myfriends VALUES (1,2);";
    $sqlSt13 .="INSERT INTO myfriends VALUES (2,3);";
    $sqlSt13 .="INSERT INTO myfriends VALUES (3,1);";
    $queryResult13=@mysqli_query($conn,$sqlSt13);
```

see the manual for `mysqli_multi_query` - [php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: ah ok ok, yeah i kept confuse using dbconnect and conn from other files -_-. Btw Sean, do you know how to add 9 more records for this? and I got like an error for this part $sqlSt13="INSERT INTO myfriends VALUES(1,2)";

Comment: Thank you so much if you could help out

Comment: I have updated with ways to do multiple VALUES. Your error could be caused by the issue the others addressed, which is that if you have that extra comma, your table `myfriends` will not be created, so your query to add values will result in an error, as there is no table to insert into.

Comment: Thank you Sean, you are a big help, I don't know what how I could reward you man -_- haha, btw, yeah I did created the second table but the error for that $sqlSt13="INSERT INTO myfriends VALUES(1,2)"; still happens. The error said syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, sorry, I am still new with this task

Comment: Unless this is a copy/paste mistake, you are missing a `;` at the line above the `$sqlSt13=...`, so it is not executing properly - `$queryResult3 = @mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sqlSt3) `.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma here that might cause an error:

`friend_id2` INT NOT NULL,

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
  $sqlMyfriends = "CREATE TABLE `myfriends` (  
  `friend_id1` INT NOT NULL,   
  `friend_id2` INT NOT NULL
  )";
```

I wish I could be at school now :)

Comment: Yeah, school :) kinda hard, but keen to develop my php skills. Thank you so much for the help btw ;). Btw, do you know why I can't populate my table, especially the second one?

Comment: Will give you a chance to use your imagination :) Go ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the following errors in code:
1) $queryResult3 = @mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sqlSt3)
Is correct: $queryResult3 = @mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sqlSt3);
 2)    $sqlMyfriends = "CREATE TABLE `myfriends`
          (
          `friend_id1` INT NOT NULL,
          `friend_id2` INT NOT NULL,
          )";
Is correct:  $sqlMyfriends = "CREATE TABLE `myfriends`
          (
          `friend_id1` INT NOT NULL,
          `friend_id2` INT NOT NULL)";
3) $queryResult3 = @mysqli_query($conn,$sqlSt3);
Is correct: $queryResult3 = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlSt3);

Code correct is:

Couldn't connect to the server!

");

        $selectData = @mysqli_select_db ($conn, $dbnm);
        if(!$selectData)
        {
            die ("

Database Not Selected

");
        }

        //1st table
            $sql =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `friends`  
          (  
          `friend_id` INT NOT NULL auto_increment,   
          `friend_email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
          `password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
          `profile_name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
          `date_started` DATE NOT NULL,  
          `num_of_friends` INT unsigned,  
          PRIMARY KEY (`friend_id`)  
          )";

        //2nd table
          $sqlMyfriends = "CREATE TABLE `myfriends`
          (  
          `friend_id1` INT NOT NULL,   
          `friend_id2` INT NOT NULL
          )";


        $query_result1 = @mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $query_result2 = @mysqli_query($conn, $sqlMyfriends);

        //populating 1st table
        $sqlSt3="INSERT INTO friends (friend_id, friend_email, password, profile_name, date_started, num_of_friends) 
                VALUES('NULL','email@email.com','123','abc','2012-10-25', 5)";
        $queryResult3 = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlSt3);


        //populating 2nd table
        $sqlSt13="INSERT INTO myfriends VALUES(1,2)";
        $queryResult13=@mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sqlSt13);


        mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>

I hope to help !